# Formatting the decimal place without converting the class numeric to character

Tags: r

I have a number, say 0.4 which is of class numeric. I wish to make it 2 decimal places without changing the class numeric. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure what you mean, but you can control the number of digits that *print* with `sprintf`.

```
sprintf("%.2f",0.4)
# [1] "0.40"
```

Programmatically, `0.4` and `0.40` are identical.

```
all.equal(0.4,0.40)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: after you use sprintf("%.2f",0.4) it returns "0.40" which is a string instead of numeric. I am finding a way to make it remain as numeric.

Comment: You can't convert `0.4` to `0.40` as numeric. They are represented by the same bits by the system. That would be analogous to as asking to convert `1` to `1`.  If you can clarify what problem you are trying to solve, maybe we can help.